# Alternativa3D 8 , how to export to AIR 3 Desktop

Tags: actionscript-3, air, 3d

I'm exporting an AS3/Alternativa3D 8 project as a desktop app, using AIR 3.4, in Windows 7.

I try CPU and Direct render mode.

When I run the app, the only thing I see is the Alternativa3D logo, and a completly black screen.

Is there an special way to do this process? Some setting in AIR or something, any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure - did you specified 'Direct' rendering mode in the app descriptor? Also, what info does Context3D.driverInfo string contains?

Comment: Hi Varnius, I specified "direct" in the descriptor, and the driver info is "DirectX9Ex" ... it's correct?

Comment: Strange then. Does camera.render() get called at least once? Or maybe you don't have any objects attached to Alternativa display tree?

Comment: Yes Varnius, I render the camera. I try opening the swf file, inside the air installation folder, and the swf run perfect ... but when I execute the Air app, get the black screen with the alternativa3D logo.